# Structural topic model (stm package) plot percentage values using plot function

Tags: r, plot, topic-modeling

In page 18 of the stm tutorial

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stm/vignettes/stmVignette.pdf

the expected topic proportions are plotted

```
plot(poliblogPrevFit, type = "summary", xlim = c(0, .3))
```

where 
poliblogPrevFit

```
poliblogPrevFit <- stm(documents = out$documents, vocab = out$vocab,
+ K = 20, prevalence =~ rating + s(day),
+ max.em.its = 75, data = out$meta,
+ init.type = "Spectral")
```

I'm trying to find out how to show in the plot the percentage values, I'm trying adding the `text` of the plot function but is not working.. how can the values be added at the right of each bar in the plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your idea to use the probabilities you need, first, a specific matrix that is generated by the stm topic model: **Theta**. It basically shows you the probability of a document belonging to a topic. Second, you need your topic labels (if you want to stick with topic 1, topic 2, etc. do that), to associate your values to.
I put together a code with my own data, but it should work for your data, too. Just keep in mind to maybe change a few things to make the code work for your own specific data.

```
## Put labels in a vector
labels <- c("Buffy", "Vampire", "Slayer", "Mr. Pointy")
## Include here your own labels, you probably have more than four

## Extract theta from the stm-model
df <- data.frame(labels)
proportion <- as.data.frame(colSums(stm_topics$theta/nrow(stm_topics$theta)))
df <- cbind(df, proportion)
colnames(df) <- c("Labels", "Probability")

## Sort the dataframe
df <- df[order(-proportion), ] 
df$Labels <- factor(df$Labels, levels = rev(df$Labels))
df$Probability <- as.numeric(df$Probability)
df$Probability <- round(df$Probability, 4)

## Plot graph
ggplot(df, aes(x = Labels, y = Probability)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 0.15), limits = c(0, 0.15), expand = c(0, 0)) + #change breaks and limits as you need
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(Probability)), #Scale in percent
            hjust = -0.25, size = 4,
            position = position_dodge(width = 1),
            inherit.aes = TRUE) + 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank())
```